# Analytic constant function

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Let $f$ be an analityc function on a domain $D$, suppose that there exist a point $z_0 \in D$ such that
$$|f(z)|\geq |f(z_0)|>0$$
for all $z \in D$. Show that $f$ must be constant in $D$

I know that if $|f|$ is constant then, $f$ is constant, but I don't know how to prove it with this information

Comment: Hint: apply the maximum modulus principle to $1/f$